# How to make a quiz in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I have to make a quiz in school, but I have a problem changing the questions and answers as the user clicks on the button which sends them to next question.
I tried using Case to change the questions as they click the button, but it doesn't seem to work.
So now i don't even know how to start the program.
I have:
**Label** - This changes into next question when the user clicks on the button.
**RadioGroup** - This holds up answers to the questions, this needs to change too.
**Button** - When user clicks on the button, RadioGroup and Label changes.
So what should I write to make sure that the questions changes when users clicks on the button?
Thanks.

Comment: *So what should I write to make sure that the questions changes when users clicks on the button?* A code, I'd say.

Comment: Increment a counter for each new question. Pick the text from an indexed list.

Comment: How do you provide your questions and answers? Files? Database? Hard coded?

Answer (score 1):

The structure of the code inside Onclick() may look like this:

```
  // (1) Save the response selected
  ...
  // (2) Increment counter
  Inc(ActualQuestion);
  //..
  // (3) Get the next Question/Responses
  GetQuestion(ActualQuestion);
```

(1) and (3) will depend on how you have stored the questions and answers.

You can get from a DataBase, File on disk, array in memory...

Comment: `if NotTheFirstClick then Save the response...` ;-)

Comment: I don't understand (@TLama). In the first click (on NextButton) you must save the first response selected.

Comment: Well, the answers are on a word document.

Comment: A Word document is not the best place from which to acquire the data.  :-(

The best would be a database.
In an excel would be a middle option (using ADO you can parse lines).
A Word file is the worst.